# Using try catch in php instead of checking for permission

Tags: php, performance

I read an interesting quote on a Python forum that it's "easier to ask for forgiveness than it is to ask for permission". I'm not too familiar with the language so I can't say whether this is garbage. From working with .NET, it is my understanding that a try catch is an expensive operation and should be there for exception cases only. Kind of like a safety net.

Is there any merit to this type of behaviour with php? As in, is it quicker to read from a file inside a try catch vs checking to see if the file can be found / read before performing the read operation. I can see how it makes the code easier to maintain, but what are the perfoance implications. Is it more of a waste to check when 99.9% of the time the check is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not a standard practice in PHP. This is, in large part, because most PHP builtins threw PHP *errors* -- not exceptions! -- prior to PHP 7.0. PHP errors could not be caught by PHP try/catch blocks, making it mandatory to use explicit checks for functions that could fail.

If your code needs to be compatible with PHP 5.6 or earlier, you can't use this convention. It may be worth experimenting with if you can mandate PHP 7.0 or later for your code, but I don't know what implications this may have for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try and catch by itself is truly quite expensive. Even when it is not used (i.e. no exception is generated), there is still some overhead that is "embedded" into the generated assembly. As for simple check whether the file exists and can be accessed, same thing happens: both of the things are system calls that are generally even more expensive. You should, however, also consider that the read operation on a file is a system call as well.

Now the question is narrowed down to what is more expensive: 2 system calls or 1 syscall with the exception handling. My assumption here (which I am somewhat confident about) is that the latter will be more expensive in case where the exception is actually being thrown, but faster in other cases. Since you've indicated that there will, in most cases, be no problems with accessing the files, it may be the case that you "should" use the exceptions. It is easier to deal with errors and does make the code a little bit more pretty (although it is arguable).

A little bit more on the code side of things: it totally depends on what your framework looks like now and what you want it to look like. You can, in fact, create a class that will deal with all this stuff in any of the two ways and they both will look clean (if done properly) and easily maintainable. If, however, you don't feel like keeping it in a separate class (or a separate file\function\universe), I would go for the exception handling.

Finally, as said before, the exception handling will generally be faster in you case, but ask yourself a question: How much of a problem is it? Do you perform the operation once per page access or do you do it multiple times? Will the page be accessed often or just once a day? How much of an impact will this create compared to all the other pages\algorithms that you have. There is a good concept know as `90/10` rule: 90% of the code is executed 10% of the time and vice versa. If this particular code is in these 90%, you shouldn't even worry about the performance as your concern should be the other 10% of the code. (You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Bottlenecks))

And one more thing: as noted by duskwuff, whatever is written here holds for PHP version >= 7.0